# How to make a reference to a DropDownList and pass it to a jQuery variable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I Have this DropDownList in my view...

```
<div class="editor-field">
 @Html.DropDownList("ProdutoId", String.Empty)
</div>
```

And I want to reference this DropDownList in my jQuery function...

```
function AddRow()
    {
       var produto = $("ProdutoId")
       $('#tabelaPedidos').append('<tr><td>' + produto  + '</td><td>daniel</td></tr>')
    }
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: You can google jquery select by id.

Comment: are you trying to move the dropdownlist or copy it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible ?

Of course it does.

You have only to change your selector to the following one:

```
var produto = $("#ProdutoId").val();
```

Comment: Thanks...with this I can get the ID of my product and if I want to get the selected value ?

Comment: @Daniel You are welcome. It's all there. Please note the val() :).